# drawing within a drawing

Tags: jquery, kineticjs

I am attempting to build an application that will allow be to draw a drawing within, a drawing within, a drawin etc...  What i have so far is on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/viciouskinid/MYYRa/

```
$(function () {

ABC.Container = function () {
    var base = this;

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ABC.Canvas = function (containerID) {
    var base = this;

    var $container = $("#" + containerID);
    base.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: containerID,
        width: $container.width(),
        height: $container.height(),
        //draggable: true,
    });
    //$container.css('height','');

    base.ui = {
        stage: base.stage,
        scale: 1,
        zoomFactor: 1.1,
        origin: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        }
    };
    base.selectedElement=null;

    base.init = function () { 
        $(window).resize(base.resize);
        $(base.stage.content).on('mousewheel', base.zoom);


        base.childgroup = new Kinetic.Group(); 
        base.layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        base.layer.add(base.childgroup);
        base.stage.add(base.layer);
    }

    base.resize = function(event) {
        base.stage.width = $container.width();
        base.stage.height = $container.height();
    }
    base.zoom = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var evt = event.originalEvent,
            mx = evt.clientX /* - canvas.offsetLeft */
            ,
            my = evt.clientY /* - canvas.offsetTop */
            ,
            wheel = evt.wheelDelta / 120; //n or -n
        var zoom = (base.ui.zoomFactor - (evt.wheelDelta < 0 ? 0.2 : 0));
        var newscale = base.ui.scale * zoom;
        base.ui.origin.x = mx / base.ui.scale + base.ui.origin.x - mx / newscale;
        base.ui.origin.y = my / base.ui.scale + base.ui.origin.y - my / newscale;

        base.ui.stage.setOffset(base.ui.origin.x, base.ui.origin.y);
        base.ui.stage.setScale(newscale);
        base.ui.stage.draw();

        base.ui.scale *= zoom;
    } 
    base.setSelectedElement = function(element) {
        if(base.selectedElement)
        {
            base.selectedElement.shape.setStroke('black'); 
        }
        base.selectedElement=element;
        base.selectedElement.shape.setStroke('red'); 
    }
    base.init();
}
ABC.Canvas.prototype = new ABC.Container();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


ABC.Element = function (x,y) {
    var base = this;         

    base.init = function () { 

        base.elements=[];
        base.shape = new Kinetic.Rect({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            //fill: 'green',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 1, 
        }); 
        base.shape.on('mouseover', base.shape_mouseover );
        base.shape.on('mouseout', base.shape_mouseout );

        base.childgroup = new Kinetic.Group(); 
        base.group = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            draggable: true, 
            layer: true,
        }); 
        //prevent even bubbling so downstream group is selected on drag not upstream group.
        base.group.on('mousedown', base.shape_mousedown );
        base.group.on('dragstart', base.group_dragstart );
        base.group.on('dragend', base.group_dragend );
        //element2.moveToTop();
        base.group.add(base.shape);
        base.group.add(base.childgroup);

        base.group.on('dblclick', base.newElement);
    } 

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

    base.shape_mouseover = function (e) { 
        e.cancelBubble = true; 
        //this.setStroke('blue'); 
        base.group.draw();
    }
    base.shape_mouseout = function (e) {
        e.cancelBubble = true;  
        //this.setStroke('black'); 
        base.group.draw();
    }
    base.shape_mousedown =  function(e) {
        canvas.setSelectedElement(base);
        e.cancelBubble = true; 
    }
    base.group_dragstart =  function(e) {
        //e.cancelBubble = true; 
    }
    base.group_dragend =  function(e) {
        //cannot select after drag
        ////
        //base.shape.moveDown();
    }
    base.dragBoundFunc =  function(p,e) { 

        var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group);

        //hold shif to allign with grid.
        if(e.shiftKey)
        { 
            var gridW=10;
            p.x = Math.round(p.x/gridW / scale.x)*gridW * scale.x;
            p.y = Math.round(p.y/gridW / scale.y)*gridW * scale.y;
        } 

        return base.fitToBound(p,scale,base.parent.shape);
    }
    base.newElement = function (e) { 
        e.cancelBubble = true; 

        // var pos=base.group.getAbsolutePosition();
        // var x=(e.x-pos.x)/canvas.ui.scale;
        // var y=(e.y-pos.y)/canvas.ui.scale;

        // var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group); 
        // var p = base.fitToBound({x:x,y:y},scale,base.shape);//not working for some reason.
        //writeMessage(messageLayer, 'x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
        var element = new ABC.Element(0,0);  

        base.addElement(element); 
                }
    base.addElement = function (element) { 
        base.elements.push(element);
        element.parent=base;

        element.group.setDragBoundFunc(element.dragBoundFunc);
        element.group.setScale(0.5);


            //fit to bounds
        element.fitElementToBound();/////////////////change to use dragboundsfunc
        base.childgroup.add(element.group); 
        canvas.setSelectedElement(element);
    } 
    base.fitToBound =  function(p,scale,shape) { 

        //Fit to bounds of parent shape.
        var boundpos=shape.getAbsolutePosition();  
        var boundsize=shape.getSize();  

        var x1=boundpos.x+boundsize.width*scale.x;
        var y1=boundpos.y+boundsize.height*scale.y;
        return {
            x: p.x<boundpos.x?boundpos.x:(p.x > x1 ? x1 :p.x),
            y: p.y<boundpos.y?boundpos.y:(p.y > y1 ? y1 :p.y)
        }
    }
    base.fitElementToBound =  function() { 

        var p1=base.group.getPosition();
        var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group);
        var p = base.fitToBound(p1,scale,base.parent.shape);
        base.group.setPosition( p.x, p.y);
    }
    base.getAbsoluteScale =  function(t) {  
        var scale = t.getScale();  
        if(t.parent)
        {
            var scale1 = base.getAbsoluteScale(t.parent);
            return {x:scale.x*scale1.x,y:scale.y*scale1.y};
        }
        return scale;
    }



    base.init();
}
ABC.Element.prototype  = new ABC.Container();

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
  function writeMessage(messageLayer, message) {
    var context = messageLayer.getContext();
    messageLayer.clear();
    context.font = '18pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
  } 

var canvas = new ABC.Canvas('container');


var element01 = new ABC.Element(0,0);  
canvas.childgroup.add(element01.group);


var element0 = new ABC.Element(10,20);

element01.addElement(element0);


var element1 = new ABC.Element(20,30);  
element0.addElement(element1);


var element2 = new ABC.Element(40,50);  
element1.addElement(element2);

canvas.stage.draw();


  canvas.stage.add(messageLayer);


});
```

i am having two issues firstly if you double click on a box it will create another smaller box within that box.  only issue is that i cant get it to position correctly witin the box when it is created.  if you find the box once it has been created (mouse wheel to zoom out) and try to drag it then it will snap back into the parent box.  it would be great if it would check if the new box was in the parent box before it was created and if not then move it.

second issue is when you create a new child box (double click on a box) and create two child boxes in the parent box. if you drag the new child box then select the other child box you wont be able to select the new child box again (it will just select the parent box).  This dosent always happen but if you play around with it it should happen for you.  How to I prevent this.

Thanks.

---

getting closer, first issue is nearly solved. a new box is moved before it is added at startup and when you double click.  only problem is if you move the main block and then double click it isnt in the correct spot.

still no luck on the second issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/viciouskinid/MYYRa/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solved it.

http://jsfiddle.net/viciouskinid/MYYRa/9/

```
    var ABC = {};

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $(function () {

        ABC.Container = function () {
            var base = this;

        }

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        ABC.Canvas = function (containerID) {
            var base = this;

            var $container = $("#" + containerID);
            base.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: containerID,
                width: $container.width(),
                height: $container.height(),
                //draggable: true,
            });
            //$container.css('height','');

            base.ui = {
                stage: base.stage,
                scale: 1,
                zoomFactor: 1.1,
                origin: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0
                }
            };
            base.selectedElement = null;

            base.init = function () {
                $(window).resize(base.resize);
                $(base.stage.content).on('mousewheel', base.zoom);


                base.childgroup = new Kinetic.Group();
                base.layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                base.layer.add(base.childgroup);
                base.stage.add(base.layer);
            }

            base.resize = function (event) {
                base.stage.width = $container.width();
                base.stage.height = $container.height();
            }
            base.zoom = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var evt = event.originalEvent,
                    mx = evt.clientX /* - canvas.offsetLeft */
                    ,
                    my = evt.clientY /* - canvas.offsetTop */
                    ,
                    wheel = evt.wheelDelta / 120; //n or -n
                var zoom = (base.ui.zoomFactor - (evt.wheelDelta < 0 ? 0.2 : 0));
                var newscale = base.ui.scale * zoom;
                base.ui.origin.x = mx / base.ui.scale + base.ui.origin.x - mx / newscale;
                base.ui.origin.y = my / base.ui.scale + base.ui.origin.y - my / newscale;

                base.ui.stage.setOffset(base.ui.origin.x, base.ui.origin.y);
                base.ui.stage.setScale(newscale);
                base.ui.stage.draw();

                base.ui.scale *= zoom;
            }
            base.setSelectedElement = function (element) {
                if (base.selectedElement) {
                    base.selectedElement.shape.setStroke('black');
                }
                base.selectedElement = element;
                base.selectedElement.shape.setStroke('red');
            }
            base.init();
        }
        ABC.Canvas.prototype = new ABC.Container();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        ABC.Element = function (x, y) {
            var base = this;

            base.init = function () {

                base.elements = [];
                base.shape = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    //fill: 'green',
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                });
                base.shape.on('mouseover', base.shape_mouseover);
                base.shape.on('mouseout', base.shape_mouseout);

                base.childgroup = new Kinetic.Group();
                base.group = new Kinetic.Group({
                    x: x,
                    y: y,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    draggable: true,
                    layer: true,
                });
                //prevent even bubbling so downstream group is selected on drag not upstream group.
                base.group.on('mousedown', base.shape_mousedown);
                base.group.on('dragstart', base.group_dragstart);
                base.group.on('dragend', base.group_dragend);
                //element2.moveToTop();
                base.group.add(base.shape);
                base.group.add(base.childgroup);

                base.group.on('dblclick', base.newElement);
            }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

            base.shape_mouseover = function (e) {
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                //this.setStroke('blue'); 
                base.group.draw();
            }
            base.shape_mouseout = function (e) {
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                //this.setStroke('black'); 
                base.group.draw();
            }
            base.shape_mousedown = function (e) {
                canvas.setSelectedElement(base);
                e.cancelBubble = true;
            }
            base.group_dragstart = function (e) {
                //e.cancelBubble = true; 
            }
            base.group_dragend = function (e) {
                //cannot select after drag
                ////
                //base.shape.moveDown();
            }
            base.dragBoundFunc = function (p, e) {

                var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group);

                //hold shif to allign with grid.
                if (e.shiftKey) {
                    var gridW = 10;
                    p.x = Math.round(p.x / gridW / scale.x) * gridW * scale.x;
                    p.y = Math.round(p.y / gridW / scale.y) * gridW * scale.y;
                }

                return base.fitToBound(p, scale, base.parent.shape);
            }
            base.newElement = function (e) {
                e.cancelBubble = true;

                var pos = base.group.getAbsolutePosition();
                var x = (e.x - pos.x) / canvas.ui.scale;
                var y = (e.y - pos.y) / canvas.ui.scale;
                // var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group); 
                // var p = base.fitToBound({x:x,y:y},scale,base.shape);//not working for some reason.
                //writeMessage(messageLayer, 'x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
                var element = new ABC.Element(x, y);

                base.addElement(element);
            }
            base.addElement = function (element) {
                base.elements.push(element);
                element.parent = base;

                element.group.setDragBoundFunc(element.dragBoundFunc);
                element.group.setScale(0.5);


                //fit to bounds
                element.fitElementToBound(); /////////////////change to use dragboundsfunc
                base.childgroup.add(element.group);
                canvas.setSelectedElement(element);
            }
            base.fitToBound = function (p, scale, shape) {

                //Fit to bounds of parent shape.
                var boundpos = shape.getAbsolutePosition();
                var boundsize = shape.getSize();

                var x1 = boundpos.x + boundsize.width * scale.x;
                var y1 = boundpos.y + boundsize.height * scale.y;
                return {
                    x: p.x < boundpos.x ? boundpos.x : (p.x > x1 ? x1 : p.x),
                    y: p.y < boundpos.y ? boundpos.y : (p.y > y1 ? y1 : p.y)
                }
            }
            base.fitToBound2 = function (p, shape) {

                var scale = base.getAbsoluteScale(base.group);
                var scale1 = base.getAbsoluteScale(shape);
                var p = base.group.getPosition();
                var size = base.group.getSize();

                //Fit to bounds of parent shape.
                var boundpos = shape.getAbsolutePosition();
                var boundsize = shape.getSize();

                var x1 = boundpos.x + (boundsize.width) * scale1.x - size.width * scale.x;
                var y1 = boundpos.y + (boundsize.height) * scale1.y - size.height * scale.y;

                //alert((boundsize.width )*scale1.x +" "+ size.width*scale.x);
                //alert(scale.x +" "+ scale1.x);
                //alert(boundsize.height +" "+ size.height);
                return {
                    x: p.x < boundpos.x ? boundpos.x : (p.x > x1 ? x1 : p.x),
                    y: p.y < boundpos.y ? boundpos.y : (p.y > y1 ? y1 : p.y)
                }
            }
            base.fitElementToBound = function () {

                var p1 = base.fitToBound2(p1, base.parent.shape);

                base.group.setPosition(p1.x, p1.y);
            }
            base.getAbsoluteScale = function (t) {
                var scale = t.getScale();
                if (t.parent) {
                    var scale1 = base.getAbsoluteScale(t.parent);
                    return {
                        x: scale.x * scale1.x,
                        y: scale.y * scale1.y
                    };
                }
                return scale;
            }



            base.init();
        }
        ABC.Element.prototype = new ABC.Container();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        var messageLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        function writeMessage(messageLayer, message) {
            var context = messageLayer.getContext();
            messageLayer.clear();
            context.font = '18pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'black';
            context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
        }

        var canvas = new ABC.Canvas('container');


        var element01 = new ABC.Element(0, 0);
        canvas.childgroup.add(element01.group);


        var element0 = new ABC.Element(100, 200);

        element01.addElement(element0);


        var element1 = new ABC.Element(200, 300);
        element0.addElement(element1);


        var element2 = new ABC.Element(400, 800);
        element1.addElement(element2);

        canvas.stage.draw();


        canvas.stage.add(messageLayer);


    });
```